# Will the CSS property "opacity" only hide content from screen readers if exactly 0?

Tags: css, accessibility, css-animations, visibility, screen-readers

I need to know if I can use `opacity: 0.01` for hiding my content visually. I need to fade in content on scroll, but if I add `opacity: 0` I am not sure how this effects screen readers and SEO. The animation works fine with 0.01 as value.

Do any of you know the answer to this? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by screen readers, but if you are worried about SEO then no, opacity will not affect SEO.

Comment: Best practice is to make the page people friendly. Algorithms are becoming smarter by the second. Just make your pages work well, and put people friendly content and experience.

Comment: @Krunx A screen reader is a a type of technology that aids the blind or visually impaired when visiting a page. They're important to consider if you're trying to comply with modern international accessibility standards. In fact, in some industries, it can be considered unlawful or discriminatory to have a website that *doesn't* comply with accessibility standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, CSS does not affect screen readers.  The only exceptions are:

- display:none
- visibility:hidden
- :before and :after pseudo elements
- (**edit**) height:0 or width:0 (some screen reader / browser combinations ignore elements with a 0 size, but not all of them)

The first two will hide the elements from the screen reader.  The last one can potentially add text to the "accessible name".  See step 2.F.ii in "[Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)".

Opacity is ignored by screen readers.  It's only changing the appearance of the element and does not remove it from the DOM.  You can set it to 0 and a screen reader will still read the element.

> Most Screen Readers will skip content with opacity: 0

I'm not sure where you got that from.  I have never seen an element with `opacity:0` skipped by a screen reader.

Comment: There certainly are screen readers that skip `opacity: 0`, much like there are screen readers that ignore elements with `height: 0`.

Comment: I do accessibility testing for a living, and all the screenreaders I've tried will consistently announce text with opacity 0 and/or height 0. I'd love to test one which skips those if you can tell us which ones they are.

Comment: @stringy Google ChromeVox, Mozilla Fangs, etc. You can check out [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) for more information, or even [this bug report](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/issues/397) for ChromeVox. You should expect text that's hidden in *any* fashion to be ignored by a ScreenReader as they continue to improve and adapt, barring the obvious `aria` attribute overrides. [More...](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/01/the-state-of-hidden-content-support-in-2016/)

Comment: @TylerRoper, ah yes, i forgot about `height:0`. i'll add that to my list.  but all the a11y testing i've done has always read opacity.  the examples you gave are somewhat non-standard.  jaws, nvda, and voiceover all handle it correctly.  i don't worry about chromevox not working because it has so many other problems that it doesn't handle correctly either.  the webaim article you mentioned doesn't talk about opacity being a way to hide elements from screen readers.

Comment: @slugolicious Understood. The WebAIM article was directed at @stringy, who had said he's never come across a screen reader that ignores `height: 0`, of which there are multiple.

Comment: @TylerRoper ah, thanks. Those readers are not commonly used by people with disabilities so I'm not sure they should be used as a basis of decision-making. Good to know how they handle things though.

Answer (score 2):

Most Screen Readers will skip content with `opacity: 0` If you want your site to be accessible I can't use this CSS property to load my content in. This is why I was thinking that maybe `opacity: 0.01`would work. But I can't find any documentation about this anywhere. Thanks for the answers regarding SEO.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the property

> opacity:0

, all that happens is that it is still there, meaning in code, in reality, it still takes the space it is supposed to, it can be used to click stuff, all hover effects will work fine, etc. Hence, it does not affect any differently on SEO or screen readers.

> Visibility:hidden

is a little different than opacity because it does not take click events. Display: none completely deletes it from the code(not the DOM though), and will affect SEO and screen readers, but that is blackhat SEO techniques which are constantly updated by Google,Bing etc to catch. Hence, display property may or may not affect the SEO, nevertheless it is not recommended at all to use such techniques. You can give an element

> opacity:0.01

and then make it back to 1 with no problems at all.

Comment: Screen readers aren't as simple as "If it's not in code, it's not there!" - they're much smarter than that. Many screen readers **do** ignore `opacity: 0`, or `height: 0`, etc. A screen readers' purpose is to convey the page to a visually impaired user as accurately as possible. Therefore the best screen readers are those that can most closely replicate what an able-sighted person would see. This means ignoring invisible elements.

Comment: I think that Google sees hidden content (also with using opacity)with a lower weight since it's hidden. I think you should be careful saying that it can be used 
 with no problems at all.

Comment: @C.Juul I meant for the task you asked. If you want to hide an element with opacity 0 or 0.01 and then slowly fade it back in, this is not blackhat SEO or anything that is frowned upon by a search engine. They will obviously notice you have done that, but if it does not affect your rank, wouldn't you say it is fine to use with no problems at all ?

Answer (score 1):

> If I add opacity: 0 I am not sure how this effects screen readers and SEO.

By adding `opacity: 0.01` (or 0) without `aria-hidden="true"`, your page will fail [1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum): The visual presentation of text and images of text has a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html)

So there is no answer for your needs. If you chose to hide from screen, you must hide it from screenreaders.